# After Effects - images get corrupted / ruined picture

Tags: after-effects, motion, transitions

As shown in the picture, the image got corrupted: flipped vertically, and damaged... 
Sometimes I get just a black picture, sometimes other image distortions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it happened, but I've found out what causes it - 
it's the frame blending interpolation, which was set to pixel-motion.

[image]

Comment: Did the original video have cuts in it? Pixel motion doesn't deal very well with scene changes.

Comment: it happens mostly in transitions... but sometimes just by itself. I guess it happens when the frame rate of the video is not fully compatible with the composition frame rate